# ASP.NET MVC routing 404

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have add a new route in a default mvc project like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
routes.MapRoute(
                name:"test",
                url:"{controller}/{userId}/{action}/{cardId}",
                defaults: new {controller="User", userId=UrlParameter.Optional, action="card", cardId=UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And I have a action method like this(with a controller name as "user"):

```
public ActionResult card(string userId, string cardId="")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cardId))
            {
                return Json(new[]{
                    new {id=456, number="1234", name="ayj"},
                    new {id=123, number="2345", name="xxx"}
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { id = 123, number = "2345", name = "xxx" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

When I visit `/user/1/card/2`, it returns the correct json, however when I visit `/user/1/card`, I expect it to return an array, but it turns out to return a `404 error`. Any one could help me?

Comment: Can you please include your other routes and the order you have them in? Thanks

Comment: Done.Can you see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you use the URL without `cardId`, route engine is using your default route, therefore 404, move your custom route above the default route.

Comment: Great! Would you please elaborate on it?I am a complete newbie.

Comment: If you have a custom route, always be careful about routes that come above it, because route engine parse the route config from top to bottom, the first route that can match the URL, will be used.

Comment: Thanks! Like you said, I have added a HomeController and index method(return a simple json),when I visit `/home/index`,it was a `404 error`,it does not match the second `default` route , why not ?

Comment: I'm not sure I what you are saying, but if now you get 404 for Home controller Index action, change your test route {controller} and {action} part to specific controller and action that you're currently using, namely user and card.

Comment: I finally understand that,it matchs the first route and can not find a `card` method in the `home` controller,so `404 error`.Thank you very much!